# Twilio returning 404 error when pointing to Controller Method of Slim Framework

Tags: php, .htaccess, twilio, slim, twilio-php

I am trying to get twilio to point to a method in order to start a call.  When I have my twimlApp pointing to `www.example.com/twilio/dial.php` I am able to make calls no problem, however when I have it pointing to a controller method `www.example.com/twilioApps/dial` I receive a 404 error when looking at the Twilio App Monitor.

Here is `twilioApps/index.php` :

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
session_cache_limiter(false);
session_start();
require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../twilio.php';
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->get('/dial', function (){
$twilioObj = new twilioPlugin;
    // get the phone number from the page request parameters, if given
    if (isset($_REQUEST['tocall'])) {
        $twilioObj->number = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['tocall']);
    }
    // wrap the phone number or client name in the appropriate TwiML verb
    // by checking if the number given has only digits and format symbols
    if (preg_match("/^[\d\+\-\(\) ]+$/", $twilioObj->number)) {
        $numberOrClient = "<Number>" . $twilioObj->number . "</Number>";
    } else {
        $numberOrClient = "<Client>" . $twilioObj->clientName . "</Client>";
    }
?>
<Response>
    <Dial callerId="<?php echo $twilioObj->callerId ?>">
        <?php echo $numberOrClient ?>
    </Dial>
</Response>
<?php
});
$app->run();
```

I do not know whether this is a Slim problem, .htaccess problem, or a Twilio issue. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so I figured it out, it was the fact that I had the [TwimlApp](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/applications) using a POST request in order to send the number to call.  However the type of route I was using in slim was a GET, all I had to do was change the Twiml App request method to GET and it worked fine.